# Merging columns within a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge two different columns within a data frame. 
So if you have columns A and B, and you want A to remain the default value unless it is empty. If it is empty you want to use the value for B.

pd.merge looks like it only works when merging data frames, not columns within an existing single data frame.

```
| A     | B    |

| 2     | 4    |
| NaN   | 3    | 
| 5     | NaN  |
| NaN   | 6    | 
| 7     | 8    |
```

Desired Result:

```
|A|

|2|
|3|
|5|
|6|
|7|
```

Comment: `df['A'].fillna(df['B'])` ? Add some data to this question and expected output.

Comment: I think your looking for [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

Comment: I added a data table to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Scott Boston for the comment on the OP:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( 
    {
        'A': [2, None, 5, None, 7], 
        'B': [4, 3, None, 6, 8] 
    } 
)

df.head()
"""
     A    B
0  2.0  4.0
1  NaN  3.0
2  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  6.0
4  7.0  8.0
"""

df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'])

df.head()
"""
     A    B
0  2.0  4.0
1  3.0  3.0
2  5.0  NaN
3  6.0  6.0
4  7.0  8.0
"""
```

Comment: So question about this, it works but what do I use if the cell's value is "-"?

Comment: You could do something along the lines of `df.loc[df['A'] == '-', 'A'] = df.loc[df['A'] == '-', 'B']
In short, wherever `A == '-'`, it will replace with the value in column `B`.